# Python: ' __init__() takes 7 positional arguments but 8 were given' -- but both statements seem wrong

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class that is called in a couple of contexts:

```
class Datamodel:
    def __init__(self, habvalues, hablist=[], orglist=[], genlist=[]):
        self.habvalues = habvalues
        self.uses_database = False
        if hablist and orglist and genlist:
            self.hablist = hablist
            self.orglist = orglist
            self.genlist = genlist
            self.uses_database = True
```

There is one method that calls this class using only the `habvalues` parameter, and it seems to work fine.  However, when called using all the parameters, with lists that are shown by my logging calls to contain valid data, I get the following error message:

> __ init__() takes 7 positional arguments but 8 were given

The calling function reads like this:

```
self.newmodel = evocontrol.Datamodel(self.habvalues, self.habRecords, self.orgRecords, self.genlist)
```

So, the error message seems to be wrong.  There are not 7 positional arguments in my code, only 4.  And only 4 are given.

What could be the source of a miscount such as this?  What kinds of things should I be looking for here?

Comment: Please include the full error message - it may be referring to a different class...

Comment: By the way... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 0):

Please, try passing the arguments as keyword arguments

```
self.newmodel = evocontrol.Datamodel(self.habvalues, hablist=self.habRecords, orglist=self.orgRecords, genlist=self.genlist)
```